# Why is only a single key being emitted by the mapper for the following hive query?

Tags: mapreduce, hive

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE psam_0604
PARTITION(day) 
select x.data, x.day
from (
  select *, rank() over (partition by `data`.dpinc order by rand()) as prk 
  from test.gpsam
  where `data`.dpinc is not null) x
where x.prk <= 3000;
```

The `test.gpsam` table is partitioned by `day`. To `test.gpsam`, I added a partition for a day from a bigger table, earlier. This bigger table is also partitioned by day. And I am running the query above.

It has two stages and only one reducer gets all the data, which I believe means that only one key is emitted by the mapper of the second stage.
Why is only one key being generated by the mapper? Is there anything I can do to get a better distribution of data among the reducers?

The job has been running at 66.67% completion since the past 18 hours.
Stats of the partition added to `test.gpsam` from the bigger table:

```
 Status: HEALTHY
 Total size:    325812129888 B
 Total dirs:    1
 Total files:   696
 Total symlinks:        0
 Total blocks (validated):  2780 (avg. block size 117198607 B)
 Minimally replicated blocks:   2780 (100.0 %)
 Over-replicated blocks:    0 (0.0 %)
 Under-replicated blocks:   0 (0.0 %)
 Mis-replicated blocks:     0 (0.0 %)
 Default replication factor:    3
 Average block replication: 3.0
 Corrupt blocks:        0
 Missing replicas:      0 (0.0 %)
 Number of data-nodes:      1146
 Number of racks:       1
```

There are like 5 blocks for every snappy compressed file in the partition.

Comment: How long is this job taking? How many mappers and reducers are being spawned? How large are the files and blocks in your source table?

Comment: @TheRandomSuit This status of the partition that I had added to `test.gpsam` from the bigger table.

Comment: Can you tell me how many mappers and reducers are being created for this job? You may need to change some of the config settings for the job because of the data volumes(303 GB).

Comment: @TheRandomSuit I had set the reducer number to 1500, but that only took affect for the first stage, for the first stage mapper were 696. For the second stage about 250 to 500 reducer were spawned.